# JQuery validate file inputs

Tags: jquery, file-upload, validation

Hi I need to validate a `file` input type :

```
<form onsubmit="return validate()">
<input type="file" name="File" class="multi" />
<input type="file" name="File" class="multi" />
<input type="file" name="File" class="multi" />
<input type="file" name="File" class="multi" />
<input type="submit" name="BtnSubmit" value="save" />
</form>
```

j query method I have created is

```
 function validate()
 {
    $(".multi").each(function(){
       var files = $(this).val(); 

       if(files=='')
       { 
          alert("No document file selected");
          return false; 
       }
    });
 }
```

Problem is its showing the alert but the form is submitting.

Comment: I can not reproduce: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oliholz/zpExL/3/)

Answer (score 1):

```
function validate(){
  $(".multi").each(function(){
   var files = $(this).val(); 
   if(files==''){ 
     alert("No document file selected"); 
   }
   return false;       
 });
}
```

your return statement should be in different block not same if block so it will work as else

Answer (score 1):

Kindly see code snippet below for validating if file submitted is a valid file type. As well as checking if a file was submitted to start with.

```
//Javascript

$("#btnUpload").click(function (e) {

        var file = $("#fileupload").val();  //Fetch the filename of the submitted file

        if (file == '') {    //Check if a file was selected
            //Place warning text below the upload control
            $(".errorDiv").html("Please select a file first.");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            //Check file extension
            var ext = file.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();   //Check file extension if valid or expected
            if ($.inArray(ext, ['txt']) == -1) {
                $(".errorDiv").html("Select valid text file (txt).");
                e.preventDefault(); //Prevent submission of form
            }
            else {
        //Do your logic here, file upload, stream. etc.. if file was successfully validated
        }
    }
});
```

//For the HTML

```
<input id="fileupload"     type="file" name="files[]" /><br />
                    <p class="reminder"> Allowed file type: .txt</p>
                    <div class="errorDiv"></div>
                    <input type="button" id="btnUpload" value="Upload File"/><br />
```

Heads up: Perform file validation on the server side as well to prevent back-end error or data injections.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are returning false for each loop. If you return false inside `$.each()` loop it means to exit `$.each` loop. So here the alert appears and it then simply exits the each.

You can achieve that task in many ways. But the simplest way is to bring a flag variable.

```
function validate() {
    $check = true;
    $(".multi").each(function(){
       var files = $(this).val(); 

        if(files=='') { 
           alert("No document file selected");
           $check = false;
           return false; // You don't want to loop, so exit each loop
        }
    });

    return $check;
}
```